# Zapier Javascript Issue

Tags: zapier

Zapier splits out my JSON arrays to two separate variables when it runs in a code action, any idea why? If I include the array in the code action, it works - but if I pull it from another step it splits it out.

Code:

```
var jsonOrg = JSON.parse(inputData.data); 
var orgList = inputData.origin;
var orgArray = orgList.split(",");
var out =[];
for (var i = 0; i<jsonOrg.rows.length; i++){
 for (var j = 0; j<orgArray.length; j++){
   if (jsonOrg.rows[i].product ===  orgArray[j]){
        out += jsonOrg.rows.id[i] + ",";
     }
   }
 }
output = [{id: 123, hello:out }];
```

Comment: show us a code please

Comment: I don't quite understand the context of your question (maybe a screenshot would help), but if you want `out` to be a string, I'd recommend building the `out` array with `.append` and then using `out.join(', ')` at the end.